How to add a big quantity of numbers in Call Directory Extension?
I need to implement a logic for adding a big quantity of numbers into the Call Directory Extension.
I use this function for generating and adding numbers:
  func generatePhoneNumbers(from pattern: String, to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    
    func generate(current: String, index: Int) {
      if index == pattern.count {
        
        if let number = Int64(current) {
          context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: number)
        }
        return
      }
      
      let char = pattern[pattern.index(pattern.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]
      
      if char == "#" {
        for digit in 0...9 {
          generate(current: current + String(digit), index: index + 1)
        }
      } else {
        generate(current: current + String(char), index: index + 1)
      }
    }
    
    // Start generation
    generate(current: "", index: 0)
  }

This approach allows me to add maximum 2_000_000 numbers but I need more. After the 2000000th number I see an error
maximumEntriesExceeded

How could I load more? Are there any ways to expand the extension capacity?

You need to create multiple CXCallDirectoryExtensions.
After you install TrueCaller you will see that the app uses 4 extension instances.
I presume it's a workaround for entries limit.

Thanks for your answer. There is a Begone app, that has just one extension in settings after installing and can add up to 100 million numbers. I want the same behavior.
